# Visually show hierarchy in data and filter out a path based on search criteria in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data as below in excel and I want show the data in graphical form showing layers of hierarchy. Also, when a search criteria like a child is searched then need to show only the path that leads to that node from top.
I am new to python and I am trying to learn visualizing hierarchy data using Python. I also checked Python Library NetworKx for this. Can somebody please guide me right direction.
Data:

```
   child  parent
1   2010    1000
7   2100    1000
5   2110    1000
3   3000    2110
2   3011    2010
4   3033    2100
0   3102    2010
6   3111    2110
```

Output:

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems to consist of two parts: searching and visualization. The library you mentioned seems well suited for both tasks, but perhaps you are looking for more lightweight solutions.

One approach would be to use some limited own code in combination with [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) (it also has excellent [python bindings](http://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)). Given the parsed data, it would go something like this:

```
from graphviz import Digraph

# child-parent pairs
data = [(2010, 1000), (2100, 1000), (2110, 1000),
        (3000, 2110), (3011, 2010), (3033, 2100),
        (3102, 2010), (3111, 2110)]

g = Digraph(format='svg')

for child, parent in data:
    g.edge(str(parent), str(child))

g.render('graph')
```

[image: graph made by graphviz]

You can also highlight nodes and edges by setting the `color` attribute. Note that Graphviz only handles visualization. You'd have to write your own `Node` and/or `Edge` classes to search for a path.